# DB2 Stored Procedure Calculate Days per month dynamically

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, days

How to write the DB2 stored procedure to calculate the DPM logic.

For example, between Jan 1, 2014 to Sept 30, 2014 – 9 records will be displayed (one record per month). For each record, DPM (days per month) needs to be calculated at runtime, dynamically and updated in the formula :

```
select (((dpm*24) / 2400) * 123) / dpm 
from xxx-table 
where date between '2014-09-01' and '2014-01-01'
```

How to ensure that the correct DPM gets updated in the above mentioned formula

**Expected Output**

```
Jan - (((31*24) / 2400) * 123) / 31
Feb -(((28*24) / 2400) * 123) / 28
March - (((31*24) / 2400) * 123) / 31
April - (((30*24) / 2400) * 123) / 30
May - (((31*24) / 2400) * 123) / 31
June - (((30*24) / 2400) * 123) / 30
July - (((31*24) / 2400) * 123) / 31
August - (((31*24) / 2400) * 123) / 31
September - (((30*24) / 2400) * 123) / 30
```

Comment: Looks like your formula always produces 1.23 as the result, so you can skip your DPM altogether.

Answer (score 0):

As @mustaccio said, your formula always simplifies down to 1.23, by moving the first dpm multiplication "out" of the first fraction:

(dpm * (24/2400) * 123) / dpm

Then, the dpm's cancel each other out, only leaving

(24/2400) * 123

Which is the constant 1.23

---

However, if you really do need a days per month calculation, you could use a recursive query to build out your list of months, and then use the [`LAST_DAY`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053630.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F5-5-3-2-71) combined with the [`DAY`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000785.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F5-5-3-2-32) scalar functions. I'm assuming you're using DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, and I think `LAST_DAY` was added in 9.7

```
WITH DATES (DTE, LVL) AS (
    SELECT CAST(@beginDate AS DATE), 0
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
        UNION ALL
    SELECT DTE + 1 MONTHS, LVL +1
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1, DATES
    WHERE DTE + 1 MONTHS <= @endDate
)

SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(DTE))
FROM DATES
```

Comment: Actually, the system would execute it as integer math, so it wouldn't cancel out.  And You don't need `LAST_DAY(...)` - Start with the 1st of the month, adding one month, then just subtract the end from the start (plus one).